# Android jetpack compose TabRow : setting alignment in TabRow

Tags: android, tabs, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to achieve something like shown in the image below. I tried TabRow with default Tab and its center aligned. I cannot achieve left alignment here. I tried the TapRow with custom tab approach as per
[Google's website](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#Tab(kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,kotlin.Function1)) but the tabs were still center aligned ( I guess its TapRow issue and not Tab).

In Tabrow, With fillMaxWidth modifier, its entire row filled and center aligned and with .width=xx.dp approach, its reduced sized tabrow but still goes center aligned. I want left aligned. How can I achieve that?

Here is my code:

```
@Composable
fun HomeCategoryTabIndicator(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    color: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface
) {
    Spacer(
        modifier
            .padding(horizontal = 10.dp)
            .height(4.dp)
            .background(color, RoundedCornerShape(topStartPercent = 100, topEndPercent = 100))
    )
}

@Composable
fun MyTab(
    onClick: (String) -> Unit,
    title: String
) {
    Column(
        Modifier
            .padding(10.dp)
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .wrapContentWidth()
            .clickable {onClick(title)},
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ) {
        Text(
            text = title,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
        )
    }
}

@Composable
private fun HomeCategoryTabs(
    categories: List<HomeCategory>,
    selectedCategory: HomeCategory,
    onCategorySelected: (HomeCategory) -> Unit
) {
    val selectedIndex = categories.indexOfFirst { it == selectedCategory }

    val indicator = @Composable { tabPositions: List<TabPosition> ->
        HomeCategoryTabIndicator(
            Modifier.tabIndicatorOffset(tabPositions[selectedIndex]),
            color = MaterialTheme.ts.colors.primary,
        )
    }

    TabRow(
        modifier = Modifier.width(330.dp),
        selectedTabIndex = selectedIndex,
        indicator = indicator,
    ) {
        categories.forEach { category ->
            MyTab(
                onClick = {
                    onCategorySelected(category)
                },
                title = when (category) {
                    HomeCategory.Market -> "Market"
                    HomeCategory.Sector -> "Sector"
                    HomeCategory.News -> "News"
                    HomeCategory.Ideas -> "Ideas"
                    HomeCategory.Events -> "Events"
                }
            )
        }
    }

}
```

This is whats expected (left aligned):
[image: This is what is expected]

This is how its showing right now (center aligned):
[image: Not left aligned]

Comment: You can put your TabRow in a Box and then update the modifier of the TabRow to align in  CenterStart

Answer (score 6):

@Anand Chaudhari hi!

For left alignment you need to use [ScrollableTabRow](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#RangeSlider(kotlin.ranges.ClosedFloatingPointRange,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.ranges.ClosedFloatingPointRange,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.material3.SliderColors)) and set edges padding to 0.

Example for your code:

```
ScrollableTabRow(
    edgePadding = 0.dp
    selectedTabIndex = selectedIndex,
    indicator = indicator,
) {
    categories.forEach { category ->
        MyTab(
            onClick = {
                onCategorySelected(category)
            },
            title = when (category) {
                HomeCategory.Market -> "Market"
                HomeCategory.Sector -> "Sector"
                HomeCategory.News -> "News"
                HomeCategory.Ideas -> "Ideas"
                HomeCategory.Events -> "Events"
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Didn't work for me ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use **ScrollableTabRow** with `edgePadding = 0.dp` instead of **TabRow**

Comment: Didn't work for me

Comment: @AndroidDev  let me see your code please